# React Redux returning array of objects, array mapping them and trying to pass function as props but getting promise error

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I'm getting data from my redux thunk and connecting it to my parent component

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
   data: state.myarticles.data
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(MyArticlesView)
```

In the very same component I have this

```
{this.props.data && this.props.data.results && 
this.props.data.results.map(this.renderArticles)}
```

which fires function that lists all components from that array

```
renderArticles (article, i) {
return (
  <Article key={i} title={article.title} status={article.status} updated={article.updated_at} id={article.id} />
)
```

}

but I also want to add to that Article component a onDelete props with a function name from my parent component so it would look like this

```
renderArticles (article, i) {
return (
  <Article key={i} title={article.title} status={article.status} updated={article.updated_at} id={article.id} onDelete={this.handleDeleteClick} />
)
```

}

but it throws me an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleDeleteClick' of undefined
```

I know that in that map function this.handleDeleteClick is not visible but have no idea how to pass it to that child components

thanks

Comment: Try `() => this.handleDeleteClick()` instead of `this.handleDeleteClick`. Looks like you are losing context in your `renderArticles` method.

Comment: or bind the `handleDeleteClick` function in your constructor

Comment: yeah I've bind that in constructor and tried with () => this.handleDeleteClick but it throws the very same error, not sure how to keep context in that array map function :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this` that refers to **React component's instance** NOT the **function** to the map function, to be as follow:

```
this.props.data.results.map(this.renderArticles.bind(this))}
```